# Excluding locations from eBay Finding API

Tags: ebay-api

Using the finditemsadvanced service as part of eBays finding API, the documentation mentions filtering results to only include specific countries. However I'd like to exclude a small list of specific countries instead. Is there an option anywhere to exclude instead of include individual countries when querying for product listings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,
only Exclude options are `ExcludeSeller` and `ExcludeCategory`
or you have to list all the Countries you want in `ListedIn` or `LocatedIn`

perhaps `MaxDistance` option can be suitable for your needs..